# property implementation must have its declaration in interface error

Tags: properties, implementation

"property implementation must have its declaration in interface" error

I have this error coming up and I am new to xcode so I am unsure what to do.

I had lots of code in a class, then i moved it to a different class and now I have numerous errors. Which dont make sense, as everything looks as it should.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize MenuScreenButton;
@synthesize HowToPlayButton;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(IBAction)HowToPlayButtonPressed:(id)sender

{
HowToPlayViewController *HowToPlayView=[[HowToPlayViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    HowToPlayView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:HowToPlayView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(IBAction)MenuScreenButtonPressed:(id)sender

{
    MenuScreen *MenuScreenView=[[MenuScreen alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    MenuScreenView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:MenuScreenView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
@end
```

Below is the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HowToPlayViewController.h"
#import "MenuScreen.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *HowToPlayButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *MenuScreenButton;

}



@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *MenuScreenButton;

@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *HowToPlayButton;

-(IBAction)HowToPlayButtonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)MenuScreenButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: You need a semi-colon,not a comma after `@synthesize MenuScreenButton` also what's in `ViewController.h`

Comment: I corrected the comma but the error still appears sadly

Comment: Ok. Firstly the properties should be lower case. Secondly are you using a recent version of Xcode

Comment: The other errors are saying 'use of undeclared identifier' for several  controllers that used to be in this class but were moved?

Comment: You may be missing an #import then, or remove the references if you don't need them. Btw if you're using a recent version of Xcode, you can declare properties with much less code- you don't need the `UIButton` declarations in the `@interface {}` block, - just the `@property` and you may not need the `@synthesize` either. You're declaring properties as `retain` - so I assume you aren't using ARC

Comment: Yes, brand new iMac on friday!:) Thanks, I got rid of half the errors through your advice. There are the errors remaining saying 'use of undeclared identifier' and mentions the name of several controllers that were previously in the class. The location of the errors are on empty lines also? Unusual.

Comment: Try doing a clean (apple-shift-k) and build again -that sometimes makes a difference

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Thanks so much for your help! Last quick question, do you know any good links to assist coding parallel arrays? Im creating a stock market game, and need random news feed pulled for random shares?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid- sorry